# How to run multiple loops simultaneously in Python?

Tags: python, loops, pseudocode

I'm trying to do something that seems very basic, but I keep getting myself stuck inside of loops that don't allow me to perform other actions. For example:

```
def functionOne():
    if x key is pressed:
        do something

def functionTwo():
    if y key is pressed:
        do something else

def functionThree():
    if z key is pressed:
        do something else

def main():
    functionOne()
    functionTwo()
    functionThree()

main()
```

I was trying to to do while loops in each function, but that locks each function in its own loop cycle. I essentially want my program to run until I press a very specific key combination from the Python `keyboard` package. I assume loops are the way to keep a program running?

Or say, if I wanted to implement this on a GUI, and only exit the program when hitting the `quit` button on the GUI, while waiting for the other buttons to be clicked to do something else.

I'm aware that I could do a giant main loop with conditions nested inside one another, but I'm hoping there is a cleaner way to do this involving functions.

Comment: If you want a GUI, use a library like TKinter. It triggers events when the user does something, and you can assign event handlers that test it.

Comment: Please look up ```threading``` and ```multiprocessing```, that will set you on the right path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:-

```
def functionOne(key):
    if key != 'x':
        return
    if x key is pressed:
        do something

def functionTwo(key):
    if key != 'y':
        return
    if y key is pressed:
        do something else

def functionThree(key):
    if key != 'z':
        return
    if z key is pressed:
        do something else

def main():
    while key != 'q':
        key = input("Enter the key :")
        functionOne(key)
        functionTwo(key)
        functionThree(key)

main()
```

Other than that you can use threading if functions are computationally heavy and key input interval is smaller than the computational time of the functions.

Answer (score 0):

you could take advantage of [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/)

first install it

`pip install pynput`

then you can achieve what you are looking for like the following example (obtained from pynput documentation):

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    try:
        print('alphanumeric key {0} pressed'.format(key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        print('special key {0} pressed'.format(
            key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} released'.format(key))
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()

# ...or, in a non-blocking fashion:
listener = keyboard.Listener(
    on_press=on_press,
    on_release=on_release)
listener.start()
```